# Django version not updating from 1.3.1 to 1.4 after BitNami install

Tags: django, bitnami

I downloaded BitNami in an attempt to upgrade from Django 1.3.1 to 1.4, however when I print django.VERSION in a python shell in the terminal, I get the following:

```
>>> print django.VERSION
(1, 3, 1, 'final', 0)
```

I do still have my Django-1.3.1 installed in my Documents folder (whereas my djangostack-1.4-1 is located in my Applications folder). When I moved Django-1.3.1 to trash though nothing changed. What other steps do I need to take to complete the update process? Thank you.

Comment: try `print django.__file__`` to see where it is imported from

Comment: Ah I see. So once I have found the location how do I go about updating python/making sure the path directs to the new/updated django version?

Comment: That depends. When you got to the terminal did you just type `python` and it runs?

Comment: OK. As Bitnami is self-contained, it's likely that you're not running the version of python that is packaged with it. You can confirm this by typing `where python` on the console and looking at the path. I'm afraid I don't know OS X, so I can't tell you where to find the Bitnami Python, or how to change your environment path to point to it. Though the output of `where python` should show all python executables on your path

Comment: I was able to update my python version, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As waitinforatrain mentions it is likely that you are not using the Python version included with your BitNami Stack. You need to load the BitNami environment first and then execute those commands.

In [this link](http://wiki.bitnami.org/Components/BitNami_console?highlight=environment) you can find how to load the BitNami environment. In your case the environment script would be named `use_djangostack`.